# Facebook fanbox - can't change locale

Tags: facebook, translation, facebook-likebox

I'm using facebook fanbox instead of likebox because fanbox has css property.
I embedded this js file:

`<script type="text/javascript" src="http://static.ak.connect.facebook.com/js/api_lib/v0.4/FeatureLoader.js.php/cs_CZ"></script>`

cs_CZ shoud have changed my locale settings, translate my fanbox but nothing happens. Is it somehow possible to change language of my fanbox (I know it's deprecated but whatever...)

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I got it!
Actually, you have to mix old API with new API (wondering how long this will work ;) )

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
    <script>
            window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
                    FB.init({ appId: 'yourPageIdHere', status: true, cookie: true, xfbml: true});
            };
            (function() {
                    var e = document.createElement('script');
                    e.type = 'text/javascript';
                    e.src = document.location.protocol + '//connect.facebook.net/cs_CZ/all.js';
                    e.async = true;
                    document.getElementById('fb-root').appendChild(e);
            }());
    </script>

<fb:fan profile_id="yourPageIdHere" stream="1" connections="0" logobar="0" width="280" css="your.cssfilehere?1"></fb:fan>
```

Answer (score 1):

*I know it's deprecated but whatever...* ... erm, yeah. That.

It's been replaced with the Like button / box (some time ago) which does take a locale.

If the old, deprecated plugin doesn't work anymore with a locale, they've disabled that feature.

Comment: Don't know. But unfortunately it's what they give you, like it or not.